# SwiftUI AnyTransition.animation not overriding animation parameters when using .offset

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a view in which I would like to use the offset transition. It is my understanding that I can use the .animation function on AnyTransition to override the animation parameters of an explicit animation.

In this simple example, I would like the Rectangle transition to be 10x longer than the text moving.

[It works when using AnyTransition.opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR8UO.gif)

[It does not work when using AnyTransition.offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVbvT.gif)

```
struct MyTestView: View {

    @State var rectangleExists = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if rectangleExists {
                Rectangle().fill().foregroundColor(.red).padding()
                    //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity
                    .transition(AnyTransition.offset(x: 100, y: 0)
                                    .animation(.linear(duration: 5)))
            }
            Text("Tap Me").onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
                    rectangleExists.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is (confirm same for Xcode 12b3)... file a feedback to Apple.